# Can't login to phpMyadmin in Wamp server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am using Wampserver 64 bit with phpMyadmin 5.0.2.Cant able to login in mysql database using username and passord.
I have used user name as: '*root*'with no password in password field. I have also checked in config.inc
file there AllowNoPassword is set to true.
Whenever I try to login, the screen shows like this.

[image: LOGIN SCREEN]

How to fix this error?

Comment: You need to start the wamp server MariaDB service.

Comment: Are you able to connect from the MySQL command line client?

Comment: @Dharman It is working from MariaDB service but, how to start wamp from MYSQL service.

Comment: @ Isaac Bennetch No , it is asked to reinstall the program.

Comment: This looks like the MySQL server instance in not started. Can you start WAMPServer and then run `Right Click wampmanager->Tools->Wampserver Config Report` It takes about 30 seconds to collect info and then creates a file called `wampConfigReport.txt` in the `C:\wamp64\` folder. Add that to your question

Comment: Did you look at the error logs?